# Auto-clicking the hyperlink in browser opens Google Play Store as web page. How do I open it as Android App?

Tags: android, google-chrome, redirect, firefox, google-play

I have a webpage, and I have a hyperlink on that webpage, pointing to our app in Google Play Store. I have also script, which clicks the link after 5 seconds. The code goes like this:

```
<html>
    <body>
        Click 
        <a id="hyperlink" 
        href="https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.disney.disneyplus">
          here
        </a>
    <script>
      setTimeout(function() {
            document.getElementById("hyperlink").click();
          },5000);
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

The page is available online at https://burger.software/disneyplus.html. Feel free to try it there yourself.

When I open that page on desktop and click the link, it opens web page of our app. Also after 5 seconds, it gets redirected to web page on play.google.com.

When I open that page on Android phone, using Google app (com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox), and I click the link, it opens the Google Play Store app with the correct page. Also if I wait 5 seconds, it opens Google Play Store app.

When I open that page on Android phone, using browser (I've tried Chrome as well as Firefox), and I click the link, it opens the Google Play Store app with the correct page as well. **However**, when I wait 5 seconds, the browser opens Google Play Store in browser as web page, not the app installed on the device.

I have also tried to submit form with method GET, instead of clicking the link, and originally the problem comes from redirect, done on server. In all these cases, the browser opens Google Play Store as web page, and not as Android app.

It seems to me that this needs to be something in my HTML/Javascript, as the problem is the same for Chrome and Firefox. Any idea what that could be?